# CodeIgniter flashdata not working after redirect

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have set the flash data like this

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('dispMessage','my message is here'));
```

I found that message in session library but not display in redirect page.
and I am use the codeigniter version 2.2.0.

Can anyone help...?

Comment: what you get for `echo $this->session->flashdata('dispMessage')` ?

Comment: can you provide the HTML/PHP in your redirect page? Can your provide your controller code as well?..Also do you receive any errors?

Comment: To add flashdata:

$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');

You can also pass an array to set_flashdata(), in the same manner as set_userdata().

To read a flashdata variable:

$this->session->flashdata('item');

Comment: Make sure that your session is alive. Falshdata should work only if you add the flashdata to a session which is alive. Check whether you've added the sess_destroy() function before your flashdata is being set

Answer (score 2):

According to the [session class page of the manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared. These can be very useful, and are typically used for
>   informational or status messages (for example: "record 2 deleted").

Try preserving the flashdata in your script immediately prior to redirecting as follows:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('dispMessage');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set flash data 
$this->session->set_flashdata('dispMessage', 'This is my message');
// After that you need to used redirect function instead of load view such as 
redirect("yourcontroller/controllermethod");

// Get Flash data on view 
$this->session->flashdata('dispMessage');
```

Comment: I have written same code as you mention above, But not working.

Comment: How do we show error without loading a page? For without load you should go with JS. LOL

Answer (score 1):

For me the flashdata was not working because the session was not alive or set at the time I had called the flashdata.
My scenario was, as soon as a user logs in, the user is redirected to a specific page in which few conditions are written to check if user has the required permission to view it. If the user has no permission, the page is redirected to a landing page with error message shown in alert. This error message was set via flashdata. And when the flashdata was being setup in the controller, the user session was not alive yet. Hence the flashdata was not set and the error message didn't show up.
I hope this solves issue for people who has similar scenario like mine.

To check if session is alive, use the below snippet before setting your flashdata:

```
 if ($this->session->has_userdata('username')) {
       echo json_encode(TRUE);
 } else {
       echo json_encode(FALSE);
 }
 exit;
```

If its false then your session is not alive yet.