# codeigniter flashdata not working as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have set flashdata in controller like

```
public function customer() {
    $data['title'] = 'Black List Management';

    if ($this->input->post('single_black')) {
        //echo 'here';return;
        $wallet = trim($this->input->post('single_wallet', TRUE));
        $reason = trim($this->input->post('reason', TRUE));
        $match = preg_match('/^01[15-9]\d{8}$/', $wallet);

       //if not valid mobile
        if ($match == 0 || !$match) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'The wallet is not valid Mobile no.');
            redirect('blacklist/index');
        }
        $is_blacklisted = $this->db->where('wallet', $wallet)->where('is_blacklisted', 1)->get('customers')->num_rows();

       //if already blacklisted
        if ($is_blacklisted > 0) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'This wallet is already in blacklist');
            redirect('blacklist/index');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reason', 'Reason', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {// if invalid form
            $this->nuts_lib->view_loader('user', 'blacklist', $data);
            return;
        } else {
            $user_id = (int) $this->session->user_id;

            $query = $this->db->where('wallet', $wallet)->where('is_blacklisted', 0)->get('customers');
            $result = $query->result_array();
            if (count($result) > 0) {// if exist uppdate
                $customer_id = (int) $result[0]['id'];
                $blacklist = array(
                    'is_blacklisted' => 1,
                    'blacklist_meta' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '|' . $user_id . '|' . $reason
                );
                $this->db->where('id', $customer_id)->update('customers', $blacklist);
            } else {// insert
                $new_blacklist = array(
                    'wallet' => $wallet,
                    'is_blacklisted' => 1,
                    'blacklist_meta' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '|' . $user_id . '|' . $reason
                );
                $this->db->insert('customers', $new_blacklist);
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Blacklisted');
            redirect('blacklist');
        }
    }
}
```

From this `customer` method redirecting to following index method when error

```
public function index() {
    $data['title'] = 'Black List Management';

    $this->nuts_lib->view_loader('user', 'blacklist', $data);
}
```

In my view file (user/blacklist.php)

```
$message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
if (isset($message)) {
     echo '<div class="alert alert-info">' . $message . '</div>';
}
```

So when get `$error` its showing flashdata nicely, **But problem** is when get same error next time (after submitting form) then flashdata not show anymore.

What I have tried so far is [CodeIgniter flashdata not working after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115835/codeigniter-flashdata-not-working-after-redirect)

I need to show `flashdata` message evry time when get `$error`

Comment: U mean without using redirect.

Comment: @Bugfixer I need redirect to `index` when error in `customer` method with flashdata

Comment: There are 2 conditions for error rite ?

Comment: see there are several `set_flashdata` in controller. one is 2 condition others is 1 ocndition

Comment: Have u tried simple $this->load->view('viewname', $data); in index method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally it works after a long effort. All you have to do is use `$this->session->keep_flashdata('message')` with `$this->session->unset_userdata('message')`

here is my solution (view file)

```
    <?php
    $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
    if (isset($message)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-info">' . $message . '</div>';
         $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
    }

    ?>
```

After that in my controller `construct` function

```
 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    .....
    $this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
}
```

it works in each error. still have some silly issue but working nicely so far

Comment: why do wee need to unset? I think .... confused @Rejoanul

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
if (isset($message)) {
 echo '<div class="alert alert-info">' . $message . '</div>';
 $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
}
```

Comment: got an idea. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this construct function in your email sent controller:

```
public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is a quite a simple one. It will only display for the first time because it will not check for the second time if the error comes in. 
The reason behind it is you have placed the flash data in a IF ..ELSE statement..which will only work for only single time.

Try this one:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')):?>
       <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?> 
       </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I think this will work for you ...

Comment: Can you update the controller function properly so that we can figure it out for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting flash message in view you can get it into your controller and pass it into your view

**Controller**

```
 <?php
    if($error){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','number is not valid');
        redirect('blacklist/index');
    }

    function index()
    {

    $error = $this->session->flashdata('message');// get you flash message

    $data = array();// create array

    //...

    $data['message'] = $error;// pass you message to array
    $this->load->view('someview',$data);// pass your message to your view
    }
    ?>
```

**View**

```
// And in your view file
<?php if($message): 
echo '<div class="alert alert-info">' . $message . '</div>';
 endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what i am doing now. But i need to redirect to method with `error message`. But this solution keep me in same method (where i submit)

Comment: When you want to redirect ??? This solution redirect to your index page with your message because we redirect to `redirect('blacklist/index');`

Comment: please see my latest updated question. hope the problem will clear now

Comment: What is this line of code `$this->nuts_lib->view_loader('user', 'blacklist', $data);`?? i ma not able to understand it!!

Comment: nothing special there. just loading view through a custom library. It loading `blacklist.php` from `user` view directory

Answer (score 0):

I do this on most projects I build in CI. This is how I do it (The HTML markup is for Foundation);

The controller:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid registration number');
redirect();
```

The view:

```
if ($error = $this->session->flashdata('error')) {
    echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box alert">';
        if (is_array($error))
        {
            foreach($error as $e)
            {
                echo '<p class="error">' . $e . '</p>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $error;
        }
        echo '<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: trying your solution, wait plz

Comment: no luck. same problem. Showing once. after that same error not showing anymore

Comment: Can you update your question with your `blacklist/index` method? As I say, I use this on most projects, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set Flash message in CI

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message','number is not valid');
redirect('blacklist/index');  //Redirect after setting flash message
```

After Redirect In your view page create DIV

```
<div class="confirm-div alert alert-info"></div>
```

Add this before `</body >`

```
<script>
    // assumes you're using jQuery
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.confirm-div').hide();
    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')){ ?>
    $('.confirm-div').html('<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>').show();
    <?php } ?>
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

got same issues in CI 3.1.11, have upgraded to CI 3.1.13 and it works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).